# Extract only object data from method invoked at runtime in java

Tags: java, methods, runtime, invoke

My runtime executable class and method

```
public class RCCustomer {
    public static Map<String, Object> getCommission(Map<String, Object> obj) {

       obj.put("commissionType", "vip");
       obj.put("commissionAmt", 50);

       return obj;
    }
}
```

Call from

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("softbliss.framework.Routines.RCCustomer");
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getCommission", Map.class);
Object i = c.getConstructor().newInstance();
returnObject = m.invoke(i, obj);
```

My output is

> {org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.map=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors, commissionType=vip, commissionAmt=50}

But i need only the key and the value from return object as like
{commissionType=vip, commissionAmt=50}

How do i get this?

Answer (score 0):

Mine doesn't print all that. I'm not quite sure where the rest of that is coming from. Consider overriding the toString method in RCCustomer

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.company.Scratch.RCCustomer");
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getCommission",Map.class);
        Object i = c.getConstructor().newInstance();
        HashMap h = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Object returnObject = m.invoke(i, h);
        System.out.println(returnObject.toString());
    }
}
```

output:

```
{commissionAmt=50, commissionType=vip}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it encourages me to about stackoverflow. My mistake was I don't understand the difference between org.springframework.validation.support.BindingAwareModelMap vs Map object. I have found my solution. no need to invoke to string of the returnObject.